# How do I recruit Shareel?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I've installed the Morrowind Comes Alive mod and found Shareel, and killed the Ordinator who guarded her. How can I get a conversation window? Whenever I interact with her, I just get the pickpocketing window.

Answer (score 2):

I killed the other Ordinator in the place. No crime penalty. Now I have my own Ordinator pet with wings and awesome summoning spells.

[image: Shaleen with Ordinator Armor]